# Ubuntu not booting: Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/

Tags: boot, grub2, fstab

I installed Flashprint 5 for my 3D printer on my Ubuntu machine, but then the computer errors with this on boot:

```
mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)
[ TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/[UUID OF /dev/sda2]
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File[square?]n /dev/disk/by-uuid/[UUID OF /dev/sda2]
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
```

I first tries some solutions that said that the Hard Drive could be full, I tried that, as my hard drive was full anyway and that did not work. I tried updating the uuid in `/etc/fstab` but that did not work either. I uninstalled Flashprint 5 and it still with just not boot. If I comment out the UUID for `/dev/sda2` (where `/boot/efi` is apparently) in `/etc/fstab/`, it will boot but not to the GUI, instead just to the terminal. 

I'm stumped on what to do. Any suggestions?

Comment: when you boot into a terminal, check if everything(your own data) is alright. If so, your desktop environment might be corrupted. try reinstalling it with `apt install --reinstall gnome`

Comment: @EmreTalha My data is there, but I can't connect to the internet, even using ethernet. Trying `gdm3` will return no error but will not show any GUI, I've also tried `startx`, but that just says that `/usr/bin/X` does not exist, but as I can't connect to the internet I can't install it.

Comment: If you need to connect with Wi-Fi, you can use CLI applications like `nmcli` or `ifconfig`. If you don't have Wi-Fi and need to connect with cable, and it does not connect automatically, `systemd-networkd` and `systemd-resolved` might not be automatically started. If they are not active, start them manually. If you really can't connect to the internet with this machine, there is a package `apt-offline`, that can install packages without an internet connection. But it might not be installed, and that would create a chicken and egg problem. If it is installed try reinstalling your DE this way.